# NodeJS - get buffer object in binary/bits form

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, buffer

I am learning Node JS.

Deal with UDP server using node js.

**I want deal with bytes by bytes on UDP packets its contain DNS query packet.**

That receive message on 'message' event, That give message as buffer object.

```
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4'); 
s.bind(53, function() {

});
s.on('message',function(msg,rinfo){
    console.log("Length = "+msg.length);
    console.log(msg.toString());
});
```

I want get received message as binary form. How can  I get message in binary form from buffer object.

I tried to read Node JS document but I can not found. Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by 'binary form'?

Comment: @Ankur: Can you answer for @vkurchatkin's question `What do you mean by 'binary form'?`

Comment: @vkurchatkin i have edit my question for remove confusion. "I want deal with bytes by bytes on UDP packets its contain DNS query packet. "

Comment: still confusing, because that's what buffers do.

Comment: @AnkurLoriya You just use `msg[index]` to access a given byte. You don't have to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert it binary, use `toString()` you have to use `toString('binary')`.

Example:

```
s.on('message',function(msg,rinfo){
       var binaryData = msg.toString('binary');
});
```

Further reading:

- [Node API docs buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)
- [How to Use Buffers in Node.js](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers)

Comment: This may be correct, but I don't think we have enough information. Your example returns a `binary` encoded `string`, which is almost never what you want if you can have a Buffer instead.

Comment: Can you comment the same on the question itself?